# Setting Browser System Clock in WDIO test file

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver, browser, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I have a wdio.conf.ts with the following config. I need to set the browsers system clock so it's the same every time i run the tests. The UI is built with React + Vite. I can set browser timezone with `browser.setTimeZone('ttt')`, but is there a way to do set a specific browser time (and increment it) in a `.spec.ts` file?:

```
export const config: Options.Testrunner = {
  autoCompileOpts: {
    autoCompile: true,
    tsNodeOpts: {
      transpileOnly: true,
      project: './tsconfig.json',
    },
  },
  runner: 'local',
  logLevel: 'error',
  bail: 0,
  waitforTimeout: 20000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  capabilities: [],
  framework: 'mocha',
  mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 60000,
  },
  baseUrl: process.env.TEST_BASE_URL,
  specs: ['path/to/tests'],
  maxInstances: 1,
  capabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      'goog:chromeOptions': {
        // args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu'],
      },
    },
  ],
  headless: true,
};
```

The test scenario is created to test a React that displays the current time (using a custom hook). I want to set it to the same time, every time the test is run:

```
  it('should display the set time', async function () {
        // time should display now
        // then increment 60 seconds
        // time should display + 1 minute on clock
  });
```

I have tried using the inbuilt `browser` methods with no luck.